# Migrating encrypted database fields when upgrading to Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, lockbox-3

**Issue**

I had to upgrade my RoR app to Rails 7 due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404242/rails-nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-activerecordrelation/68407146#68407146). When making this upgrade, my db columns which were being encrypted with the [Lockbox gem](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox) were no longer able to be read as Rails was using the native decryption to try and decrypt the fields. I posted about it as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/issues/132), but am also wondering if anyone else has a solution for migrating the data out of one encryption format and into the new native encryption that will be shipping with Rails 7.0 (Currently the stable version of Rails is 6.1.4 and Rails 7.0.alpha is on the main branch on GitHub)

**Code**

app/models/journal_entry.rb

```
class JournalEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :prayer_journal

  encrypts  :content
  validates :content, presence: true  
end
```

db/schema.rb

```
create_table "journal_entries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "prayer_journal_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.text "content_ciphertext"
    t.index ["prayer_journal_id"], name: "index_journal_entries_on_prayer_journal_id"
  end
```

Console output of the first Journal Entry

```
#<JournalEntry:0x00007f95364745c8
 id: 1,
 prayer_journal_id: 1,
 created_at: Sat, 15 May 2021 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 17 Jul 2021 03:12:34.951395000 UTC +00:00,
 content_ciphertext: "l6lfumUqk9RqUHMf0aVUfL2sL+WqkhBmHpyqKqMtxD4=",
 content: nil>
```

Answer (score 10):

After a few hours pouring over the Rails guides and various blog posts talking about the new native encryption, I was able to figure out how to migrate the data. It is a multi-step process, but I felt that I would place it here for future help to others.

First, I do want to say that it may be possible to list other encryption/decryption providers if I am reading [the guides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#custom-key-providers) correctly. I was unable to figure that out, and so decided to use what I do know to create a solution.

**How I came up with the solution**

I noticed that in my schema there wasn't actually a "content" column, but rather a "content_ciphertext" column and when lockbox was being called in `encrypt :content`, it would encrypt and place it in that column. And I could call `JournalEntry.first.content` to have it decrypt the `content_ciphertext` field and provide the plain text. This is why, after upgrading to Rails 7 and the native encryption, it kept saying that the column `content` was `nil`; because in actuality, there was no column by that name. Rails 7 uses the exact naming within the schema, not appending 'ciphertext' or the like to the column name.

Having this knowledge solved the rest for me.

**Steps to solve**

1. BEFORE UPGRADING THE RAILS VERSION: Create a migration to add a content field to the tables with the encrypted data. In my case there where three tables. So, I ran this code: `rails g migration AddUnencryptedContentFieldToDatabaseTabels`

and changed the migration file to look like this:

```
# db/migrate/*******_add_unencrypted_content_field_to_database_tabels.rb

class AddUnencryptedContentFieldToDatabaseTabels < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    add_column    :journal_entries,        :unencrypted_content,         :text
    add_column    :prayer_requests,        :unencrypted_content,         :text
    add_column    :prayer_request_updates, :unencrypted_content,         :text
  end

  def down
    remove_column :journal_entries,        :unencrypted_content
    remove_column :prayer_requests,        :unencrypted_content
    remove_column :prayer_request_updates, :unencrypted_content
  end
end
```

That done, I wrote a rake task to go through and copy all the encrypted fields over to an unencrypted column.

```
# lib/tasks/switch_encryption_1.rake

desc 'This goes through and copies encrypted data to a non-encrypted field to start the process of migrating to new native encryption.'
task :switch_encryption_1 => :environment do
    puts "Journal Entries where content needs to be unencrypted: " + JournalEntry.where(unencrypted_content:nil).count.to_s
    JournalEntry.where(unencrypted_content:nil).each do |j|
        j.update(unencrypted_content:j.content)
    end
    puts "Journal Entries where content needs to be unencrypted after code run: " + JournalEntry.where(unencrypted_content:nil).count.to_s

    puts "Prayer Requests where content needs to be unencrypted: " + PrayerRequest.where(unencrypted_content:nil).count.to_s
    PrayerRequest.where(unencrypted_content:nil).each do |r|
        r.update(unencrypted_content:r.content)
    end
    puts "Prayer Requests where content needs to be unencrypted after code run: " + PrayerRequest.where(unencrypted_content:nil).count.to_s

    puts "Prayer Request Updates where content needs to be unencrypted: " + PrayerRequestUpdate.where(unencrypted_content:nil).count.to_s
    PrayerRequestUpdate.where(unencrypted_content:nil).each do |u|
        u.update(unencrypted_content:u.content)
    end
    puts "Prayer Request Updates where content needs to be unencrypted after code run: " + PrayerRequestUpdate.where(unencrypted_content:nil).count.to_s
end
```

Those both written, I could now deploy the code to production. Once deployed I would run `rake db:migrate` in the production console, then `rake switch_encryption_1` to go through and decrypt and copy all of the fields to the new column.

I could also then test to make sure that the data is actually copied and decrypted before proceeding.

2. Back in development, I can now update my `Gemfile` the new Rails main branch as I have decrypted the fields. So, I change the `Gemfile` to this:

   `gem 'rails',        :github => 'rails/rails', :branch => 'main'`

You will then need to create the encryption keys by running `bin/rails db:encryption:init` in the console and copying the values to the credentials file. If you don't know how to do that, you run this code `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit` and copy the values into that file:

```
active_record_encryption:
  primary_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  deterministic_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  key_derivation_salt: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then follow the prompts to save and exit. For me that is Control + the capital letter 'O' to Write Out and then Control + the capital letter 'X' to exit. This will work for development. Since Rails 6, we have been able to set different credentials for the different environments. So, you'd copy the same data, but in the console run `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit --environment production` to get to the production credentials. (REMEMBER TO KEEP THESE KEYS VERY SAFE AND TO NOT CHECK THEM INTO VERSION CONROL)

Then I created another migration `rails g migration AddContentFieldToDatabaseTabels`

and changed the migration file to look like this:

```
# db/migrate/*******_add_content_field_to_database_tabels.rb

class AddContentFieldToDatabaseTabels < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    add_column    :journal_entries,        :content,             :text
    add_column    :prayer_requests,        :content,             :text
    add_column    :prayer_request_updates, :content,             :text

    remove_column :journal_entries,        :content_ciphertext
    remove_column :prayer_requests,        :content_ciphertext
    remove_column :prayer_request_updates, :content_ciphertext
  end

  def down
    remove_column :journal_entries,        :content
    remove_column :prayer_requests,        :content
    remove_column :prayer_request_updates, :content

    add_column    :journal_entries,        :content_ciphertext,  :text
    add_column    :prayer_requests,        :content_ciphertext,  :text
    add_column    :prayer_request_updates, :content_ciphertext,  :text
  end
end
```

You'll probably notice that I also added in code to remove the old encrypted column. This is because that will no longer be used and I have already verified that the content is now saved in the `unencrypted_content` columns.

I then wrote another rake task to go through and copy all of the data from the `unencrypted_content` columns to the `content` columns. And since my models already have the code `encrypts  :content` from before with the Lockbox gem, I don't need to add that to the models to let Rails know to encrypt those columns.

```
# lib/tasks/switch_encryption_2.rake

desc 'This goes through and encrypts the unencrypted data and copies it to the encrypted field to finish migrating to new native encryption.'
task :switch_encryption_2 => :environment do
    JournalEntry.all.each do |j|
        j.update(content:j.unencrypted_content)
    end

    PrayerRequest.all.each do |r|
        r.update(content:r.unencrypted_content)
    end

    PrayerRequestUpdate.all.each do |u|
        u.update(content:u.unencrypted_content)
    end

    puts "Finished Encrypting"
end
```

Now, deploy. Your production credentials should also have been deployed for encryption.  Now run this in the production console: `rake db:migrate` and `rake switch_encryption_2`. After I did that, I verified that the encryption worked.

3. I can now just create another migration in development to delete the unencrypted table columns. Like so: `rails g migration DeleteUnencryptedContentFieldFromDatabaseTables`

db/migrate/*******_delete_unencrypted_content_field_to_database_tabels.rb

```
class DeleteUnencryptedContentFieldToDatabaseTabels < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
    def up
        remove_column :journal_entries,        :unencrypted_content
        remove_column :prayer_requests,        :unencrypted_content
        remove_column :prayer_request_updates, :unencrypted_content
    end

    def down
        add_column    :journal_entries,        :unencrypted_content,  :text
        add_column    :prayer_requests,        :unencrypted_content,  :text 
        add_column    :prayer_request_updates, :unencrypted_content,  :text
    end
end
```

Push that to production and run `rake db:migrate`.

At this point, everything should be migrated to the new native Rails 7 encryption.

I hope that this helps future coders. Happy Coding!

**BONUS SECTION**

For those paranoid among us, or working with very sensitive data and needing to make sure that the unencrypted columns are no more. Here is a third rake task that I created that goes through and writes over the columns with `nil`. You can run this before deploying the migration to delete the columns. But, really, this is probably just overkill:

```
desc 'After verifying that the data is now encrypted and able to be decrypted, this task will go through and erase the unencrypted fields'
task :switch_encryption_3 => :environment do
    JournalEntry.all.each do |j|
        j.update(unencrypted_content:nil)
    end

    PrayerRequest.all.each do |r|
        r.update(unencrypted_content:nil)
    end

    PrayerRequestUpdate.all.each do |u|
        u.update(unencrypted_content:nil)
    end

    puts "Finished Enrasing Unencrypted Data. You will need to run a new migration to delete the 'unencrypted_content' fields."
end
```

Comment: There is a missing step here before running `switch_encryption_1.rake`. You need to add some logic in your controllers or models to update the `unencrypted_content` column if the `content_ciphertext` column changes. This is necessary if a user is updating a record while the rake task is running and it has already processed the given record. The same approach is needed when migrating from using `unencrypted_content` to `content`.

Comment: Thank you @AbM for that suggestion. I didn't add that because I notify my users of a scheduled maintenance whenever I need to do a database change like this, then I place my app in maintenance mode so no one can make changes. That is just my work flow, thus no need for the controller code. But, others definitely may need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After Rails 7 migration, you need to change encryption keywords to continue using Lockbox (and decide later if you need to migrate to rails encryption method).

before Rails 7 :

`encrypt: :login, key: Rails.application.credentials.lockbox_key`

after Rails 7 :

`has_encrypted: :login, key: Rails.application.credentials.lockbox_key`

since `encrypt:` is used by rails 7 encryption.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this Lockbox gem related issue you can simply

1. change the Lockbox gem version to one that is greater than

`v0.6.4`

2. and change the

`encrypts`

to

`lockbox_encrypts`

in the model class. That is it.

Because the new Rails 7 encryption also uses `encrypts` the Lockbox team added a new `lockbox_encrypts` method.

You can find the related GitHub discussion [here](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/issues/107).

However, if you want to start using the Rails 7 encryption (and to remove Lockbox gem from your app) this is not what you need to do.